# How do i set a callback function to my ajax call with parameters, outsite the ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, callback

I have a ajaxForm class that do the ajax and i must set a callback for it, using the attribute data-callback on the form element... being like:

```
<form method="post" action="/something" class="ajaxForm" data-callback="someFunction">
<!-- FORM STUFF -->
</form>
```

Then i have the JS

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.ajaxForm').bind('submit', function(ev) {
            $.ajax({
                //AJAX STUFF
                success: function(response) {
                    call_the_data_callback_function(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there any way i can call the javascript function with the name set on data-callback with one parameter that would be the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows
inside your success function

```
var callBackFunc = $(".ajaxForm").attr("data-callback");//get the function name
    callBackFunc.call(this,response); // call the function
```

this should work.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object myCallbackFunction has no method 'call'

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes in google i could find the following solution:

```
<script>
   var functionName = 'myCallbackFunction';
   fn = window[functionName];
   if (typeof fn === 'function') {
      fn(parameters);
   }
</script>
```

Simple, easy, cool! :D